# How to prevent app name, icon and theme of the launcher activity from getting changed on cross store updates

Tags: android, android-theme, android-launcher

I have my Android application listed on both Google Play Store as well Samsung Galaxy App Store. The application has different name, icon as well the splash screen for apk uploaded to the Samsung App Store. These strings, icons and images are configured using the build variants.

Since the apk's are signed with the same certificate and have the same package id (as well as the version code), they can be installed and further updated from either of the stores.

Since they have different name/icon/splash screen, if the app installed via Samsung App Store is updated via the Google Play Store, the name/icon/splash screen change back to Google Play Store ones and vice versa. I want to retain these properties on the basis of the Store from which they were installed from and not from where they were updated.

Is there any workaround to prevent this from happening?

Possible things I am already aware of

- I have found a reference to  using which I can update the app name and icon but the same technique does not works with theme/splash screen. It also comes with own sets of drawbacks.
- Using different package id for different stores. This would prevent the root problem of cross-store updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using a different version for the non Google builds. The version code **should** be kept significantly higher so that at least few more releases on Google Play Store still fall behind the non Google builds. Since version code of the application installed via non Google Store would always be higher than that of the builds present in Google Play Store, Google Play Store would never trigger an update.